# Slickgrid spreadsheet plugin numeric sort

Tags: jquery, sorting, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with this filtering plugin:

https://github.com/danny-sg/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/blob/master/ext.headerfilter.js

This has a sorting feature:

```
filterPlugin.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    dataView.fastSort(args.column.field, args.command === "sort-asc");

});
```

That works great for text filtering, but most of my data is numeric. When I filter numbers 1 to 1000 it sorts as 1, 10, 100, etc.

I have a numeric sort function that I found online but it just jumbles up the numbers in random order.

```
function NumericSorter(a, b) {
  var x = a[sortcol], y = b[sortcol];
  return sortdir * (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
}
```

I believe the issue is because it is designed to work with the built-in slickgrid click to sort function, so I need to adapt it to work with the spreadsheet sort, however I don't understand the sort function enough to do this.

This is my code so far:

```
filterPlugin.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    dataView.fastSort(args.column.field, args.command === "sort-asc");
    //MD added
    if (args.column.field == "linenum") {
       dataView.sort(NumericSorter, args.sortAsc);
       // alert("numeric sort");
    } else {
       dataView.fastSort(args.column.field, args.command === "sort-asc");
       // alert("text sort");
    }
 });
```

How can I achieve numeric sort?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that `fastSort` is a workaround for pre-IE9, and doesn't need to be used unless you want to support pre-IE9.

```
/***
 * Provides a workaround for the extremely slow sorting in IE.
 * Does a [lexicographic] sort on a give column by temporarily overriding Object.prototype.toString
 * to return the value of that field and then doing a native Array.sort().
 */
function fastSort(field, ascending) {
  ....
```

In Example-4-model, the following sort code is used.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  sortdir = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
  sortcol = args.sortCol.field;

  if (isIEPreVer9()) {
    // using temporary Object.prototype.toString override
    // more limited and does lexicographic sort only by default, but can be much faster

    var percentCompleteValueFn = function () {
      var val = this["percentComplete"];
      if (val < 10) {
        return "00" + val;
      } else if (val < 100) {
        return "0" + val;
      } else {
        return val;
      }
    };

    // use numeric sort of % and lexicographic for everything else
    dataView.fastSort((sortcol == "percentComplete") ? percentCompleteValueFn : sortcol, args.sortAsc);
  } else {
    // using native sort with comparer
    // preferred method but can be very slow in IE with huge datasets
    dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
  }
});
```

Note that all the fancy logic (including the `sortcol` variable) is to workaround for IE8 or less, and other browsers need basically one line of code:

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
});
```

and this is the comparer:

```
function comparer(a, b) {
  var x = a[sortcol], y = b[sortcol];
  return (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
}
```

You don't need to worry about the sort direction in the comparer - the DataView takes care of that. The comparer is a standard javascript comparer (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)).
As such, if the numbers are stored as numerics, you don't need to do anything. If numbers are stored as text, though, you would need to convert them to numbers as part of the compare operation.

Comment: Thanks Ben for all the background information on sorting, much appreciated. I have simplified my code as per yours and it's working fine for sorting strings, but not numbers. So I assume the issue is that they are strings, not numbers. It's strange because I add them to the dataview in this format `d["linenum"] = i + 1;`, which gives me 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: Even with this code it's still sorting the numbers as text, can you provide further help please Ben?   `function comparer(a, b) {
  var x = a[sortcol], y = b[sortcol];

  //if it's a number:
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(x))) {
    x = parseFloat(x);
  }
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(y))) {
    y = parseFloat(y);
  }

  return (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
}`